# How much powder does 1 TBSP of Cumin seeds yield when crushed?

Tags: spices

How much powder does 1 TBSP of Cumin seeds yield when crushed? I have a recipe that calls for Cumin seeds to be crushed but I could not find whole seeds at the store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little bit less than 1tbsp, maybe 4/5ths of a tablespoon.

Comment: Sounds roughly right.  I was going to say a little under a tsp.